# Rewrite in Subpath 404 urls with Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

Currently I have a main redirect to the home of my webserver. However I would like to treat the subpaths with redirect after a 404 was not for the home and yes for the subpath, that with multiple subpaths. That not to repeat the rules, I must deal with a REGEX, however I don't know how to insert these rules and return to the current subpath.

home

```
www.foo.com.br
```

subpath

```
www.foo.com.br/machine
www.foo.com.br/cloud
www.foo.com.br/air
```

today

```
# define error page
error_page 404 = @notfound;

# error page location redirect 301
location @notfound {
    return 301 /;
}
```

would like answer 404

```
www.foo.com.br/machine/test123
```

go to

```
www.foo.com.br/machine/
```

Answer (score 1):

The REGEX used to pick up the first field and redirect after a 404:

```
  error_page 404 = @notfound;

  location @notfound {
    rewrite ^/([\w-]*)/.* /$1/ permanent;
```

In your php block put the `fastcgi_intercept_errors` set to on

```
  location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    # intercept errors for 404 redirect
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `rewrite` rules before the `return` statement to match the specific subdirectories you want treated differently.

For example:

```
location @notfound {
    rewrite ^/(machine|cloud|air)/. /$1/ permanent;
    return 301 /;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: Richard, thanks for the reply. 
The regex created was as follows: 
```error_page 404 = @notfound;

   location @notfound {
     rewrite ^/([\w-]*)/.* /$1 permanent;
   }
```

The expected result is the first field if the url doesn't exist. it's working. 

But I have another problem, when doing the redirect this is downloading the `index.html` from the home page. 

Have you saw anything like this?

Comment: You can test the redirection using `curl -I`, but you are probably missing a trailing `/` in the rewritten URI.

Comment: Thank you, you're correct. I'll close this case.
I realized that to do the redirect is just taking everything that is * .php, then yes everything works ok, but if I try with a normal path `foo.com.br/air/` is not going, and downloading `index .html` from the home page. 
I think it's the `try_files` config.

Comment: Richard, This worked great! Thanks!  

If you can take a look, please. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55589837/how-to-insert-read-path-in-try-files-rewrite-error-in-nginx)