# How to insert read path in try_files? Rewrite Error in Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

A redirect was created for when returning "404" and go to the first directory of the URL, ex:

`foo.com.br/air/uknwfileerror` > `foo.com.br/air`

But this is not working just for `.php` extension

`foo.com.br/air/uknwfileerror.php` > `foo.com.br/air`

```
  listen *:443;
  server_name portal-dev.foo.com.br ;
  root  /var/www/novo;

  ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:20m;
  ssl_session_timeout 20m;

  resolver 1.1.1.1;
  set $proxy_foops_https 'https://proxy-portal-dev-stg.foo.com.br';
  set $proxy_foops_http 'http://proxy-portal-dev-stg.foo.com.br';

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/wildcard.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/wildcard.key;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/dev.foo.com.br.ssl.access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/dev.foo.com.br.ssl.error.log;

  error_page 404 =  @notfound;

  location @notfound {
    rewrite ^/([\w-]*)/.* https://$server_name/$1/ permanent;
  }

  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '$http_origin';
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'origin, x-requested-with, content-type';
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials 'true';

  location = /portal/{
    rewrite        ^ https://$server_name/ permanent;
  }

  location /portal/ {
      index index.php index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /portal/index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ wp-login\.php$ {
    allow   all;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  }


  location / {
      location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf|woff)$ {
          expires 7d;
          access_log off;
      }
      index index.php index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
      fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  }

  location /cas/ {
    proxy_pass $proxy_foops_https;
    proxy_set_header Host      portal-dev.foo.com.br;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
  }

  location /auth-service {
    proxy_pass $proxy_foops_https;
    proxy_set_header Host      portal-dev.foo.com.br;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
  }
}
```

using `Curl -I` I see that it is returning 301 with the url `foo.com.br/air/uknwfileerror.php` but with the path `foo.com.br/air/uknwfileerror` it returns only 200 and I dowload the home page.

The expected one is that when entering a path that of 404, also returns to the first block typed:

`foo.com.br/air/uknwfileerror.php` > `foo.com.br/air`

`foo.com.br/air/uknwfileerror` > `foo.com.br/air`

Comment: Try adding `try_files $uri =404;` to the `location ~ \.php$` block.

Comment: The problem is not when there is a .php file, with .php is working. 
We tried `try_files $uri =404` for the location / but it is `301` in loop.